# Availability of BridgeConnect in Magento

Tags: magento

One of our clients is thinking of buying an Enterprise Edition, due to his requirement of using the Exact CRM Services with Magento. But today, to my utter astonishment, I’m not finding any inclusion of ”**BridgeConnect**” module in either the ”**Enterprise**” or the ”**Professional**” Editions.

Can anybody from the SO please highlight, whether Magento still provides this ”**BridgeConnect**” module with the ”**Enterprise**” or the ”**Professional**” Editions?

If this module is not being provided, then when will Magento provide this module?
Or, is Magento planning to provide any better solution module, instead of the ”**BridgeConnect**” module?

This is very much urgent for us, and will be very very grateful for some quick responses.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: if you are a enterprise client then you have access to magento paid support and asking such question there would give you exact answer.

Comment: Hoping I can offer context here for anyone else looking -- I'm told that they've removed the module from their archived releases of Magento EE. I asked Support if they could provide the module itself directly, and they declined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use Adeptia or JitterBit (or any other ETL system) to connect to Magento API. Both offer generic export/import options (files, DB, FTP, webservices) and have plugins to integrate with various 3rd party platforms. That is the way BridgeConnect (eBridge software) worked - they offered ready-made connectors to various platforms. Magento also allows to quite easily extend its API so you can add any webservices that are missing from current core API (eg creating order in Magento)

Comment: Thanks for this update. But it will be really helpful if you can provide some code snippet.

Answer (score 4):

According to this [forum thread](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/59406/) there is an official answer:

> ... we’re no longer offering Bridge Connect. We’re sorry for the inconvenience ...

This module was included in previous Enterprise versions, but they have removed it in the latest ones. Maybe they are going to release something new and more flexible, but who knows...

If you want to integrate with some particular ERP/CRM you should look closer on extensions available on Magento Connect or write your own.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](http://www.ontapecommerce.com/magento) it is included. Even if you're not yet an enterprise licence holder you can still contact Magento's customer support and ask them directly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's actually in your support section near the download for EE itself.